# How can we prove that a reduction exists?

Tags: reductions, polynomial-time-reductions

**Problem:** I have two computational problems, $A$ and $B$. We know that $A \in \texttt{Psearch}$ and I want to prove that $A \leq_p B$ for all problems $B$.

**Goal:** It is my understanding that my goal is to prove that there is a polynomial time reduction $R$ from $A$ to $B$ given that $A \in \texttt{Psearch}$.

I know from lecture that if $A \leq_p B$ and $B \in \texttt{Psearch}$, $A \in \texttt{Psearch}$. How do you go from knowing $A \in \texttt{Psearch}$ to $A \leq_p B$?

Comment: Maybe you meant $B\neq\emptyset,\Sigma^*$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What does it mean that $A\in P_{search}$? What knowledge does that give us on $A$? Now, try to use this knowledge to directly construct a reduction from $A$ to $B$. Notice that we don't really need $B$: this property is entirely proven from the information we know about $A$.

Comment: I am still very new to these reduction problems. When you say "construct a reduction from A to B", how do I do this? My normal thought process is to create an algorithm, prove its correctness, then prove that the algorithm runs in polynomial time (still somewhat confusing for me). Since we know that A $\in$ Psearch, we know that it already runs in Poly-time. Would I then use some Turing Machine that solves B and use that in some way on A?

Comment: Notice the *direction* of the reduction: you will need to "solve A using B". But why would you need B? you can just solve A directly. Please go over the definition of reduction and use it directly - you will be less confused this way.

Comment: Thank you, I will do some research on the topic.

Comment: Here is something I have found: In order to prove that A can be reduced to B in polynomial time, we must transform the inputs of A to inputs of B such that the transformed problem has the same output as the original. An instance x of A can be solved by applying this transformation to produce an instance y of problem B, giving y as the input to an algorithm for problem B and return its output. Is this close to what you were hinting at?

Comment: Yes. Now you will have to figure how to turn those instances of $A$ into instances of $B$ (hint: this only works if $B\neq\emptyset,\Sigma^*$. Why?)